# Como fazer com que a classe CSS não afete quem tiver uma determinada classe?

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho um `ul` onde ele é um menu em que os itens que não estão dentro de um `ul` filho têm a tag `dropdown-toggle`. Os itens que estão em `ul` filho não tem essa tag.

A classe `.navbar-solid` é aplicada ao `<ul>` pai. Eu não quero que ela aplique as propriedades do `a` em quem não tiver a classe `dropdown-toggle`, ou em outras palavras, dentro do `ul` filho. No código abaixo, ela está aplicado para todos os `a`.

```css
.navbar-solid  {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
}
.navbar-solid img {
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}
@media (min-device-width: 1100px) {
    .navbar-solid a {
        color: green !important;
        transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
    }
    .navbar-solid a:hover, i:hover {
        color: blue !important;
        transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-solid">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="xxx">
             Aaaaa
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="xxx">
             Bbbbb
        </a>
    </li>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown">
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="xxx">
                  Sub-item
             </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="xxx">
                  Sub-item 2
             </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
<ul>
```

Como faço essa filtragem em CSS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para fazer isso basta adicionar a classe `dropdown-toggle` da sua tag `<a>` depois da indicação da tag no css:

```
a.dropdown-toggle
```

Veja a funcionar:

```css
.navbar-solid {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
}
.navbar-solid img {
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}
@media (min-device-width: 1100px) {
    .navbar-solid a.dropdown-toggle {
        color: green !important;
        transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
    }
    .navbar-solid a.dropdown-toggle:hover, i:hover {
        color: blue !important;
        transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-solid">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="xxx">
             Aaaaa
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="xxx">
             Bbbbb
        </a>
    </li>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown">
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="xxx">
                  Sub-item
             </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="xxx">
                  Sub-item 2
             </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Se Entendi bem, você deseja adicionar o efeito de transparência somente aos links com a classe `dropdown-toggle`

**css**:

```
.navbar-solid  {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
}
.navbar-solid img {
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}
@media (min-device-width: 1100px) {
    .navbar-solid .dropdown-toggle {
        color: green !important;
        transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
    }
    .navbar-solid .dropdown-toggle:hover, i:hover {
        color: blue !important;
        transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
    }
}
```

No caso acima como você quer adicionar a transparência somente a classe `dropdown-toggle`, você pode usar a classe em vez do `a`, pois ele selecionara todos os `a` dentro do elemento .navbar-solid. Se você não quiser ou não puder usar a classe `dropdown-toggle`, você pode adicionar ao seus links uma nova class.

**css**:

```
.navbar-solid  {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
}
.navbar-solid img {
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}
@media (min-device-width: 1100px) {
    .navbar-solid .link-transparent {
        color: green !important;
        transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
    }
    .navbar-solid .link-transparent:hover, i:hover {
        color: blue !important;
        transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
    }
}
```

e no html::

```
<ul class="navbar-solid">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle link-transparent" href="xxx">
             Aaaaa
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle link-transparent" href="xxx">
             Bbbbb
        </a>
    </li>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown">
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="xxx">
                  Sub-item
             </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="xxx">
                  Sub-item 2
             </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
<ul>
```

Explicando, a gente tem a classe `link-transparent` que só sera alterada quando a tela do usuário tiver no minimo 1100px, pois ele ta dentro do seu @media.

Answer (score 2):

Só para deixar registrado, tbm consegue fazer o que quer com seletores de atributos CSS:

```css
.navbar-solid {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
}

.navbar-solid img {
  filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}

@media (min-device-width: 1100px) {
  .navbar-solid a[class*="dropdown-toggle"] {
    color: green !important;
    transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
  }
  .navbar-solid a[class*="dropdown-toggle"]:hover,
  i:hover {
    color: red !important;
    transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-solid">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="xxx">Aaaaa</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="xxx">Bbbbb</a>
  </li>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="xxx">Sub-item</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="xxx">Sub-item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="xxx">Teste</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
<ul>
```

Comment: Quem negativou poderia por favor dizer o que está errado, para mim poder aprender tbm?

Comment: Não fui eu que dei -1, mas como está o `a:hover` será aplicado a todos os casos. Por acaso a cor que está é a mesma que a *default*. Se mudar `color:blue` para `color:red` já vai notar a diferença.

Comment: Hmmm... certo Jorge agora entendi, não tinha me atentado ao **hover**, embora a lógica seja a mesma adiconando o seletor no hover.

Answer (score 1):

```
.navbar-solid > li a
.navbar-solid > li a:hover, i:hover
```

```css
.navbar-solid > .dropdown {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
}
.navbar-solid img {
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
}
@media (min-device-width: 1100px) {
    .navbar-solid > li a {
        color: green !important;
        transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
    }
    .navbar-solid > li a:hover, i:hover {
        color: blue !important;
        transition: background-color 1s ease 0s;
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-solid">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="xxx">
             Aaaaa
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="xxx">
             Bbbbb
        </a>
    </li>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown">
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="xxx">
                  Sub-item
             </a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
             <a class="dropdown-item" href="xxx">
                  Sub-item 2
             </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
<ul>
```

Comment: Mas aí faz o contrário do que pedi. Eu quero que aplique somente nos `<a>` que estiver nos `<li>` do `<ul>` pai, não do filho.

Comment: @CypherPotato Entendi errado... veja agora.

Comment: @CypherPotato poderia ser `li` em vez de `ul` nesta resposta. Só que na próxima vez que fizer uma qualquer `li` sem `dropdown-toggle` vai apanhar na mesma esse CSS.

Comment: @CypherPotato o rbz editou, mas mesmo assim todas as `li` sem `dropdown-toggle` seriam afetadas.

Comment: @JorgeB. Corrigi! rs... E dessa forma que fiz, teria que usar o dropdown-toggle como referência as opções "pai".